# Oracle Materialized View with ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, materialized-views

I am trying to create the following Materialized View with ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION but I can't find where is the issue.

I have three master tables with the corresponding materialized view logs and the columns needed. Can anyone help me ?

Thank you

```
create materialized view log on alfaods.OdsReceivable with rowid, sequence ( dueDate , recvChargeTypeId, scheduleId , amount ) , primary key including new values for fast refresh;

create materialized view log on alfaods.OdsChargeType with rowid, sequence ( code ), primary key including new values for fast refresh;

create materialized view log on alfaods.OdsScheduleMain with rowid, primary key including new values for fast refresh;
```

Then the MV is

```
create materialized view alfaods.mv_max_fn_date
TABLESPACE TBDATA
CACHE
LOGGING
NOCOMPRESS
NOPARALLEL
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION
AS 
SELECT max(receivable.dueDate) as finalDate, 
       schedule.id as scheduleId , 
       receivable.recvChargeTypeId as recvChargeTypeId, 
       receivable.scheduleId as receivableSchId , 
       receivable.amount as recamount , 
       chargeType.code as ChargTypecode
                   FROM ALFAODS.OdsReceivable receivable
                        INNER JOIN ALFAODS.OdsChargeType chargeType on receivable.recvChargeTypeId = chargeType.id 
                        INNER JOIN ALFAODS.OdsScheduleMain schedule on receivable.scheduleId = schedule.id 
where 
receivable.amount NOT IN (0.01, 0.00)
AND chargeType.code = 2 
group by schedule.id , receivable.recvChargeTypeId , receivable.scheduleId , receivable.amount , chargeType.code 
;
```

When I try to create it , I got this error

```
SQL> create materialized view alfaods.mv_max_fn_date
TABLESPACE TBDATA
CACHE
LOGGING
NOCOMPRESS
NOPARALLEL
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION
AS
SELECT max(receivable.dueDate) as finalDate,
       schedule.id as scheduleId ,
   receivable.recvChargeTypeId as recvChargeTypeId,
   receivable.scheduleId as receivableSchId ,
   receivable.amount as recamount ,
   chargeType.code as ChargTypecode
                   FROM ALFAODS.OdsReceivable receivable
                        INNER JOIN ALFAODS.OdsChargeType chargeType on receivable.recvChargeTypeId = chargeType.id
INNER JOIN ALFAODS.OdsScheduleMain schedule on receivable.scheduleId = schedule.id
where
receivable.amount NOT IN (0.01, 0.00)
AND chargeType.code = 2
group by schedule.id , receivable.recvChargeTypeId , receivable.scheduleId , receivable.amount , chargeType.code
 25  ;
AND chargeType.code = 2
                      *
ERROR at line 23:
ORA-32361: cannot ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION for the materialized view


Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL>
```

It looks like there is a problem with the where condition, so I tested it without where

```
SQL> create materialized view alfaods.mv_max_fn_date
TABLESPACE TBDATA
CACHE
LOGGING
NOCOMPRESS
NOPARALLEL
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION
AS 
SELECT max(receivable.dueDate) as finalDate, 
       schedule.id as scheduleId , 
       receivable.recvChargeTypeId as recvChargeTypeId, 
       receivable.scheduleId as receivableSchId , 
       receivable.amount as recamount , 
       chargeType.code as ChargTypecode
                   FROM ALFAODS.OdsReceivable receivable
                        INNER JOIN ALFAODS.OdsChargeType chargeType on receivable.recvChargeTypeId = chargeType.id 
                        INNER JOIN ALFAODS.OdsScheduleMain schedule on receivable.scheduleId = schedule.id 
--where 
--receivable.amount NOT IN (0.01, 0.00)
--AND chargeType.code = 2 
group by schedule.id , receivable.recvChargeTypeId , receivable.scheduleId , receivable.amount , chargeType.code 
;

INNER JOIN ALFAODS.OdsScheduleMain schedule on receivable.scheduleId = schedule.id
                                                                       *
ERROR at line 20:
ORA-32361: cannot ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION for the materialized view
```

**UPDATE**

I ran the DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited echo on long 99999999 longchunksize 99999999 
declare
    a sys.ExplainMVArrayType;
begin
    dbms_mview.explain_mview('SELECT receivable.recvChargeTypeId as recvChargeTypeId, 
       receivable.scheduleId as scheduleId , 
       receivable.amount as recamount , 
       chargeType.id as ChargeID,
       max(receivable.dueDate) as finalDate
                         FROM ALFAODS.OdsReceivable receivable
                        INNER JOIN ALFAODS.OdsChargeType chargeType on receivable.recvChargeTypeId = chargeType.id 
group by receivable.recvChargeTypeId , receivable.scheduleId , receivable.amount , chargeType.id',a);
    dbms_output.put_line('Explain MV '
        || a(1).mvowner || '.' || a(1).mvname);
    for i in 1..a.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line(
            rpad(a(i).capability_name, 30)
            || ' [' || case a(i).possible
                       when 'T' then 'TRUE'
                       when 'F' then 'FALSE'
                       else a(i).possible
                       end || ']'
            || case when a(i).related_num != 0 then
                   ' ' || a(i).related_text
                   || ' (' || a(i).related_num || ')'
               end
            || case when a(i).msgno != 0 then
                   ' ' || a(i).msgtxt
                   || ' (' || a(i).msgno || ')'
               end
        );
    end loop;
end;
/

Explain MV .
PCT                            [FALSE]
REFRESH_COMPLETE               [TRUE]
REFRESH_FAST                   [FALSE]
REWRITE                        [TRUE]
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT      [FALSE] join may produce duplicate rows in mv
(2059)
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT      [FALSE] MV is not fast refreshable even with view
merging (2154)
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML  [FALSE] FINALDATE (193) mv uses the MIN or MAX
aggregate functions (2086)
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML  [FALSE] see the reason why
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT is disabled (2146)
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML  [FALSE] mv uses the MIN or MAX aggregate
functions (2086)
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ANY_DML     [FALSE] see the reason why
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML is disabled (2161)
REFRESH_FAST_PCT               [FALSE] PCT FAST REFRESH is not possible if query
contains an inline view (2196)
REWRITE_FULL_TEXT_MATCH        [TRUE]
REWRITE_PARTIAL_TEXT_MATCH     [TRUE]
REWRITE_GENERAL                [FALSE] the reason why the capability is disabled
has escaped analysis (2141)
REWRITE_PCT                    [FALSE] general rewrite is not possible or PCT is
not possible on any of the detail tables (2158)
```

Comment: The first hit leads to `Doc ID 2608076.1`

Comment: @MarmiteBomber , the document you refer says only this  To avoid ORA-32361 error. MVIEW should be aggregate join view . The view is aggregated , so it must be something else

Comment: Sorry I am not in front of a 12.2 instance today.  Two suggestions.  Try creating w/o `ON QUERY COMPUTATION` and running DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW on your mview.  I am not sure if Oracle extended that procedure for OQC or not, but it may give insight.  Failing that, try to remove the inner joins and build with only the `OdsReceivable` table to start.  Add joins one at a time to see where it starts failing.  I agree your problem does not seem to be bug 24731557

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak , thank you. I post the result of the EXPLAIN_MVIEW, but I don't understand what limitation of OQC I am hitting

Comment: Your MV is not even fast refreshable due to this "join may produce duplicate rows in mv".    You have primary keys (not just unique indexes) and foreign keys declared on your tables?  If not, define them and try the whole thing again (and update the DBMS_MVIEW output if it is still not working).

Comment: FYI, this message "mv uses the MIN or MAX aggregate functions" is also likely to be a problem for you.  `MAX()` won't be fast refreshable since you have a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: The tables have only PKs. There are no FK constraints. Is that the reason for the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could create the MV like this. I had to remove the MAX function from the MV, instead I would use it in the query which was something I wanted to avoid. Anyway, here the script

```
SQL> @rebmv.sql
SQL> drop materialized view log on alfaods.OdsScheduleMain ;

Materialized view log dropped.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.05
SQL> drop materialized view log on alfaods.OdsChargeType ;

Materialized view log dropped.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
SQL> drop materialized view log on alfaods.OdsReceivable ;

Materialized view log dropped.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.04
SQL> drop materialized view alfaods.mv_max_fn_date ;

Materialized view dropped.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.14
SQL>
SQL> create materialized view log on alfaods.OdsScheduleMain with rowid, sequence ( maturityDate,alfascheduleidentifier,scheduleStatus,terminationDate,totalAssetCostFinanced,capitalOutstanding,activationDate,agreementId,invCusId,dealerid,invCompanyId,agrCompanyId ), primary key including new values for fast refresh;

Materialized view log created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.06
SQL>
SQL> create materialized view log on alfaods.OdsChargeType with rowid, sequence ( code ) , primary key including new values for fast refresh;

Materialized view log created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
SQL>
SQL> create materialized view log on alfaods.OdsReceivable with rowid, sequence ( dueDate,recvChargeTypeId,scheduleId,amount ), primary key including new values for fast refresh;

Materialized view log created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02
SQL>
SQL> create materialized view alfaods.mv_max_fn_date
  2  TABLESPACE TBDATA
  3  CACHE
  4  LOGGING
  5  NOCOMPRESS
  6  NOPARALLEL
  7  BUILD IMMEDIATE
  8  REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND
  9  ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
 10  ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION
 11  AS
 12  SELECT count(*) as contador,
 13         receivable.dueDate as finalDate,
 14         schedule.id as scheduleId,
 15         receivable.recvChargeTypeId as recvChargeTypeId ,
 16             receivable.scheduleId as recScheduleId
 17          FROM ALFAODS.OdsReceivable receivable
 18        INNER JOIN ALFAODS.OdsChargeType chargeType on receivable.recvChargeTypeId = chargeType.id
 19            INNER JOIN ALFAODS.OdsScheduleMain schedule on receivable.scheduleId = schedule.id
 20  where
 21  receivable.amount NOT IN (0.01, 0.00)
 22  AND chargeType.code = 2
 23  group by receivable.dueDate , schedule.id , receivable.recvChargeTypeId, receivable.scheduleId
 24  ;

Materialized view created.

Elapsed: 00:00:21.94
SQL>
SQL> create index alfaods.idx_mv_max_fn_date on alfaods.mv_max_fn_date ( scheduleId ) nologging nocompress tablespace tbdata ;

Index created.

Elapsed: 00:00:04.13
SQL>
SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('ALFAODS','MV_MAX_FN_DATE', method_opt=> 'FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE AUTO', cascade => true);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:08.36
SQL>
SQL> exec dbms_mview.refresh ('ALFAODS.MV_MAX_FN_DATE','F');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:01.46
SQL>
```